# My last excel formatting issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to be able to display a difference in seconds as (+4.15) or sometimes negatively as (-4.15) and include the parentheses and plus/minus sign.

How can I use a formula to display 34.47-30.32so it comes out knowing whether or not the difference is positive or negative 4.15?

This is solved now except my next issue is small, but any number ending in 0, such as 4.10, will display as 4.1, without the extra 0. Using the formula given earlier, =TEXT(B1-A1,"+##.##;-##.##"), I can't format this to show the extra zero in the format. Is it possible?

Comment: Kindly do not repeat post questions that have answers you have ignored.

Comment: One was different, congrats on not reading the whole thing

Comment: ... and congrats in return on ignoring my answer, the explanation I provided and the information within the link I supplied.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=TEXT(B1-A1,"+#.00;-#.00")
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly